# How to get column values dynamically in Oracle Apex Interactive Grid

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-20.2, interactive-grid

I want to concatenate a static sql statement with a dynamic string represent for some of dynamic column which have defined by another sql statement like this
`select column1, column2, '|| v_select ||' from my_table`. **v_select** have example value like `column3, column4`
And I use this new sql as the source of Oracle APEX interactive grid. But it only generate `column1 and column2`, `column3, column4` couldn't generate.
Can someone can help me to resolve my problem.
Thanks a lot

Comment: This cannot be done as a normal query. The interactive grid metadata is generated when the interactive grid is created so the number of columns and datatypes need to be known at create time. It can be done with source type "Function body returning SQL Query" but I'm not sure this was already available in apex 20.2

Comment: Thanks Koen, I have to tried using Function body returning SQL Query, I also create a function to return SQL in database and call this function through a variable in Function body returning SQL Query but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This can only be done using a type of *"Function body returning SQL Query"*. This doesn't need to be a function defined as such in the database, it just needs to be an anonymous pl/sql block with a `RETURN` statement. The help has some examples.

Example on the sample emp/dept dataset. In the example the variable `l_additional_cols` has a list of additional columns:

```
DECLARE
  l_additional_cols VARCHAR2(512);
  l_select VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  l_select := q'~
select ename, %0 from emp
~';
  l_additional_cols := ' job, sal';
  l_select := apex_string.format(l_select, l_additional_cols);
  RETURN l_select;
END;
```

Note that the returned select statement needs to be valid *at compile time*, so make sure to have a default value.